# Issues with running a Python program with Cron

Tags: python, cron

I am trying to run a Python script called `probemon.py` in `cron` (`crontab -e`) and cannot get it to work. The path to the file is `/home/pi/probemon.py` and this must be run with the `sudo` command usually (i.e. `sudo python probemon.py`). I have tried many methods, including:

```
52 23   *   *   *    sudo python /home/pi/probemon/probemon.py
```

and yet nothing works. Any ideas about how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the command to the sudo-users crontab instead of trying to run it with a sudo from a normal users crontab. I think what happends is that "sudo ..." will ask for the sudo-password, and wait in this stage forever, since noone is providing one.